# How can I calculate the Average CPU usage of every process in C

Tags: c, linux, performance, linux-kernel, kernel

In need to calculate the total CPU occupy time of process and divide that by the current time minus the process start time.

So far I have the following code:

```
    #include <linux/time.h>

    cputime_t kernel_time = task_cputime->stime;  //total time running in kernel space
    cputime_t user_time =  task_cputime->utime;  //total time  running in user space
    cputime_t total_occupy = kernel_time + user_time;  //Total CPU occupy time

    //convert to ms
    unsigned long total_occupy_ms = mulhdu(total_occupy, __cputime_msec_factor);
```

How would I use `do_gettimeofday` to get current time and `task_strcut->real_start_time` in ms? It may be easy, but I am fairly new to kernel programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct timeval tv;
unsigned long timeofday_in_ms = 0;
unsigned logn real_start_time_in_ms = 0;
do_gettimeofday(&tv);
timeofday = jiffies_to_ms(timeval_to_jiffies(&tv));
real_start_time = jiffies_to_ms(timespec_to_jiffies(&current->real_start_time));
```

All the function involving above are self-explanatory and can be used in kernel